# How do I programmatically invoke a maven build with my Eclipse plug-in project?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, m2e, eclipse-jdt

I am currently writing an Eclipse plug-in that allows users to create Maven projects with some template Java code already included.

I'm trying to have some custom controls to `mvn clean build` or `mvn clean deploy` a project. So far I have a *Custom Package* and a *Custom Deploy* `IHandler` tied to some menu contributions. They use **Maven Invoker** to build it something like this:

```
MessageConsole console = ...
console.clearConsole();
console.activate();

MessageConsoleStream consoleOut = console.newMessageStream();
consoleOut.setActivateOnWrite(true);

try (
    PrintStream stdout = new PrintStream(consoleOut, true))
{
    // Invoke Maven
    InvocationRequest request = new DefaultInvocationRequest();
    request.setPomFile(new File(project.getFile("pom.xml").getLocation().toOSString()));
    request.setGoals(Arrays.asList(goals));

    Invoker invoker = new DefaultInvoker();
    invoker.setOutputHandler(new PrintStreamHandler(stdout, true));
    invoker.execute(request);
} catch (MavenInvocationException e) {
    ...
}
```

This worked fine on my Windows 7 environment but had a number of issues when I tested it on my Mac environment, namely **nothing printed to console** and required that **M2_HOME MUST be set**. There were other little problems and I really felt like I was re-inventing the wheel, and that I should be able to leverage Eclipse existing m2e functionality.

So I started to look into `ILaunchConfigurationDelegate` and found the `MavenLaunchDelegate` class. It has *restriction warnings* but I'm not concerned. I also found the `ExecutePomAction` which brings up the very familiar Maven Build run configuration panel, but I want to use my own custom shortcut.

I was hoping to write my own `ILaunchShortcut` with only one choice: *package* or *deploy*, and invoke an appropriate Maven build from both this shortcut and my custom handlers. The problem is... **I'm lost**.

I'm looking for advice or resources on **the best way to invoke a maven build programmatically from an Eclipse plugin**.

Comment: I would manually invoke "Run As... -> Maven Build..." and specify the exact build you want to perform.  Then programmatically query the existing list of run configurations to find the specific class and configuration values for the launch configuration representing the maven build you just performed manually.  You ought to be able to create and launch similar configurations from your tool.